# How do I retrieve the class of the TD in the below HTML with Selenium/XPath?

Tags: xpath, selenium

I have the below HTML and code which I am using to retrieve the class of the `<td>`.

```
<td class='dataValueRead RV2' style=''>Constant</td>
```

**

```
driver.findElement(
  By.xpath("//td[contains(normalize-space(.),'Constant')]")
).getAttribute("class")
```

It gives me a blank value as output. Any clues where I a going wrong?

Comment: The XPath is okay. What does querying for just `//td` and `//td[contains(normalize-space(), 'Constant')]` return?

Comment: @user561337: That XPath expression should select that `td` element

Answer (score 3):

**Just use**:

```
//td[contains(normalize-space(.),'Constant')]/@class
```

**Do note** that the above expression may select more than one node.

**To select only the N-th node from these**, use an XPath expression of this kind (for N=1):

```
   (//td[contains(normalize-space(.),'Constant')]/@class)[1]
```

**If none of these are selecting any node the reason may be**:

1. `//td[contains(normalize-space(.),'Constant')]` doesn't select any node because there is no `td` whose string value contains the string `'Constant'`. Are you sure you are using the exact capitalization? XPath *is* case-sensitive and `'constant'` is not equal to `'Constant'`.
2. `//td[contains(normalize-space(.),'Constant')]` doesn't select any node because there is a default namespace. In this case you have to register a namespace and use its prefix in the XPath expression (there are a lot of questions and answers about this -- read them):  `//x:td[contains(normalize-space(.),'Constant')]`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use XPath to access the attribute directly ( `td/@class` )?